# How to get notification from google drive sheet on edit?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I want to send notification to third party application when someone make changes in document stored in google drive.

can someone please help me that how to bound script with any document and when someone make changes in that script should run and send notification to third party application.

I have tried the following code But it is not working.

```
    function onEdit(event){

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var editedolumn = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(editedRow, editedolumn, 1, 6);
  Logger.log(values); 
  getSession();
}

function getSession(){  
 var payload =
   {
     "username" : "username",
     "password" : "password",
   };
  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
   };  
  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://abcd.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=login.do" , options);
  Logger.log(login);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
  Logger.log(sessionDetails);
  sendHttpPost(sessionDetails);
}


function sendHttpPost(data) {
  var payload = {"category" : "network","short_description" : "Test"};
  var headers = {"Cookie" : data} 
  var url = 'https://abcd.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident';
  var options = {'method': 'post','headers': headers,'payload': payload,'json': true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To send notification to third party application when someone make changes in document stored in google drive**

Based from this [Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/fsYwbZ3hpjc), this feature hasn't been added yet. However, you may set notifications in a spreadsheet to find out when there's some modifications done in your spreadsheet. To set [notifications in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588?hl=en&rd=1):

1. Open the spreadsheet where you want to set notifications.
2. Click Tools > Notification rules.
3. In the window that appears, select when and how often you want to
   receive notifications.
4. Click Save.

**And, to bound script with any document**

You may find the complete guide in [Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#top_of_page) documentation. As mentioned,

> To create a bound script, open a Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms file, then select **Tools > Script editor**. To reopen the script in the future, do the same thing. Because bound scripts do not appear in Google Drive, that menu is the only way to find or open the script.

Comment: I have updated my question.Can you please take a look and suggest me the what is the wrong with code.Thanks!!